# SilverStripe ModelAdmin single record

Tags: php, silverstripe

I've recently learned to create custom CMS sections in the back-end using class `ModelAdmin` and linking them using `private static $managed_models = array('Contact');` to a DataObject named `Contact`.

My goal is to create a new section named "Contact" which holds a few contact details (phone, email etc). These are singular fields, not multiple records.

Unfortunately this setup (linking to dataobject) creates a sort of GridField in the back-end that creates multiple "Contact" records with the fields Phone, Email etc.

**How can I create a custom CMS section that holds a singular entity of given Fields?**

Comment: you can prevent creation of further DO with permissions like canCreate https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/customising_the_admin_interface/modeladmin/#permissions ...but probable you also could just  add it to a Tab in SiteConfig https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/configuration/siteconfig/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding a single `Client` `DataObject` we can store these variables in the site settings using a [`SiteConfig` extension](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/configuration/siteconfig/#extending-siteconfig).

To do this we create a `SiteConfig` extension with the variables and fields we would like:

**mysite/code/extensions/CustomSiteConfig.php**

```
class CustomSiteConfig extends DataExtension {

    private static $db = array(
        'Phone' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'Email' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'Address' => 'Varchar(255)'
    );

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Contact', TextField::create('Phone'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Contact', TextField::create('Email'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Contact', TextField::create('Address'));
    }
}
```

We activate the extension:

**mysite/_config/config.yml**

```
SiteConfig:
  extensions:
    - CustomSiteConfig
```

We can now use the the variables in any of our templates:

```
<% if $SiteConfig.Phone %>$SiteConfig.Phone<% end_if %>
<% if $SiteConfig.Email %>$SiteConfig.Email<% end_if %>
<% if $SiteConfig.Address %>$SiteConfig.Address<% end_if %>
```

Comment: That works perfectly! How could I take all this and put it in a *new* button named "Contact" rather than placing them in Settings (SiteConfig)? Is there a simple way or does this require huge piles of code?

Comment: My recommendation would be to leave it in a tab in the Settings panel.

Comment: If you really wanted to store the data in separate `DataObject` you could use something like [`GridFieldHasOneRelationHandler`](https://github.com/dnadesign/gridfieldrelationhandler) and add that to the settings tab. If you wanted the data to be controlled through a completely separate tab on the left you could create a custom admin panel by extending [`LeftAndMain`](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/customising_the_admin_interface/how_tos/extend_cms_interface/). But this is a fair bit of work to add a few fields.

Comment: Actually, this might be exactly what you are after:
https://github.com/burnbright/silverstripe-hasonefield

Answer (score 4):

This is not what ModelAdmins are for. They are meant to manage your dataobjects.

That said, I could only think of two solutions:

Filtering the gridfield and limiting it to one datarecord.

Your dataobject

```
class Contact extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = [
        'Name' => 'Varchar',
        'Phone' => 'Varchar',
        'Email' => 'Varchar'
        // etc, etc
    ];
}
```

Your ModelAdmin

```
class ContactModelAdmin extends ModelAdmin
{
    private static $managed_models = array(
        'Contact'
    );

    private static $url_segment = 'contact';

    private static $menu_title = 'My Contact Admin';

    public function getList()
    {
        $list = parent::getList();

        $list = $list->filter('Name', 'EagleEye')->limit(1);

        return $list;
    }
}
```

Or you might just wanna get rid of the gridfield and create some formfields, which you can populate.

```
class ContactModelAdmin extends ModelAdmin
{
    private static $managed_models = array(
        'Contact'
    );

    private static $url_segment = 'contact';

    private static $menu_title = 'My Contact Admin';

    public function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null) {

        $form = parent::getEditForm($id, $fields);

        $gridFieldName = $this->sanitiseClassName($this->modelClass);
        $form->Fields()->removeByName($gridFieldName);

        $form->Fields()->push(
            TextField::create('Name', 'Name', 'EagleEye')
                ->performReadonlyTransformation()
        );
        $form->Fields()->push(
            TextField::create('Phone', 'Phone', '0123456789')
                ->performReadonlyTransformation()
        );
        $form->Fields()->push(
            TextField::create('Email', 'Email', 'EagleEye@domain.com')
                ->performReadonlyTransformation()
        );

        return $form;
    }
}
```

I hope this was what you were looking for.

Comment: Great input. I'm not familiar with getEditForm, but is setup basically just hiding the gridfield? If so, it would be a bit hacky. Can you perhaps suggest the right way to achieve the result without using ModelAdmin? What I'm basically after is a CMS section that's the same as `Settings` but with different form fields.

Comment: You could use the second example I gave you, removing the GridField and adding the contactfields. But as you said, that's a bit of a hacky way. You could also use @3dgoo example. That would be better practise in this case I think. That way your contact details will be at Settings in a tab called Contact.

Answer (score 0):

The README of [jonom/silverstripe-someconfig](https://github.com/jonom/silverstripe-someconfig) says: It's ️ `ModelAdmin` and ⚙️ `SiteConfig` baby and this is what OP asked for.